# Long polling using rxjs

Tags: rxjs, long-polling

I want to create long polling client for a web service using RxJS.

Targeted endpoint that supports blocking requests sends `x-index` header to a client with a value representing current state of the endpoint. This `x-index` value is being sent in subsequent requests as a query parameter so the endpoint responds only when `x-index` changes or when request timeouts.

1. --> client sends first request to the server
2. <-- server immediately responds with a `x-index` header
3. --> client sends blocking request with a value of `x-index` as a paramter
4. <-- request is suspended until change of the state or until timeout, then server sends the response
5. if `x-index` is changed then pass data to subscriber && repeat from step 3.

I don't know how to create that loop of server requests with changing `x-index` parameter. Anybody can help, please?

Comment: don't quite understand the flow between 3,4, does client send x-index at a fix interval?

Comment: What happens when the client tries to send multiple requests with the same `x-index`?

Comment: @FanCheung No, client always waits for the server to respond.

Comment: @martin Doesn't matter if the client sends one or multiple requests. Request does not change the state of the server.

Comment: What should happen if server timeout

Comment: @Peracek For example when the clients send 5 requests with the same `x-index` do you expect 5 responses or only one?